# pymzml install error in Anaconda Spyder

Tags: pip, installation, anaconda, spyder

I use Anaconda Spyder. Python 3.6 version.

OS is Windows 7 64bit

I wrote in IPython console.

```
!pip install pymzml
```

and then I get this error message.

```
Collecting pymzml
  Using cached pymzml-2.0.0.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: pymzml
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pymzml: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pymzml: finished with status 'error'
  Complete output from command C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c 
"import setuptools, 
 tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-8r_4srar\\pymzml\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, 
__file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d 
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpb89hzuklpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  [ pymzML ] Warning: no plotly installed ...
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pymzml
  copying pymzml\decoder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pymzml
  copying pymzml\file_interface.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pymzml
  copying pymzml\ms_numpress.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pymzml
```

....

```
  running build_ext
  cythoning C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-8r_4srar\pymzml\Numpress\PyNumpress.pyx to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-8r_4srar\pymzml\Numpress\PyNumpress.cpp
  building 'PyNumpress' extension
  error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified.: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\PlatformSDK\\lib'
```

How to install pymzml in Anaconda Spyder environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There are two important things to note about your question:

1. Your command is failing because you don't have the Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 compiler installed in your system. Without this compiler, it won't be possible to install this package.
2. Our IPython console is meant to run Python code, or very simple external commands with the `!foo` syntax. For more complex tasks (like installing packages), you need to use a real terminal (i.e. `cmd.exe` in your case).